# Rename Published UWP App

Tags: uwp, windows-store

I am trying to rename a published app on the Microsoft Store. I followed the steps given in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/manage-app-names#rename-an-app-that-has-already-been-published but now both the old and new name are being marked as "in use". The store listing uses the old name, but the installed app uses the new name.

The app in question is https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9P4WTLLQ26HJ

What can I do to get rid of the old name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Update the display name in the package manifest and make a new package.
2. Create a new submission (update) for your app in the Dev. Center.
3. Go to the "Packages" page of the new submission.
4. Delete all the packages (which are available from previous submissions) and click Save.
5. Go to the "Store Listing" page of the new submission.
6. On the top of the page, you can now choose new product name for your app, from a list of registered names.
7. Go back to "Packages" page and re-upload your package(s).

I'm not sure if there is a better way to enable choosing product name in the store listing page but this one works well.